# What happens when the first Cubone comes to existence? Does it has a skull to wear, or not?

Tags: pokemon

I'm sure that the Pokedex says that a Cubone has the skull of it's dead mother, so if the first one appears, does it have a copy of it's skull, or not?

Comment: *mother did you mean?

Comment: [It's turtles, all the way down!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down#Background_in_Hindu_mythology)

Comment: My theory is that Cubone is actually Darth Vader.